# Entity Framework 5 database first - null reference in production only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I've been using EF5 db first for some time in a .net 4.5 web project, and it's working well.

I have one query that throws a null reference when calling Count() or ToList() or Any() etc.

```
        lastQuery =  dbContext.Set<T>();
        logger.Info("last Query: {0}", lastQuery); // this shows the correct query 
        lastQuery.ToList(); // only when the query is executed, null reference is thrown
```

lastQuery.ToString() shows the correct db query.

this code works from localhost, dev, qa, and localhost pointing to uat/prod database.

entity framework 5 assembly (EntityFramework.dll 5.0.0.net45) is included in deployment and referenced locally.

It only breaks when this code is run on uat/prod server.

it was my suspicion that asp.net mvc 4 was not up to date, so i deployed a standalone install, but that didn't fix it.

**looking for ideas on how else to troubleshoot it, or what components may be missing in prod etc..**

*call stack:*

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at System.Data.EntityKey.ValidateTypeOfKeyValue(MetadataWorkspace workspace, EdmMember keyMember, Object keyValue, Boolean isArgumentException, String argumentName)
 at System.Data.EntityKey.ValidateEntityKey(MetadataWorkspace workspace, EntitySet entitySet, Boolean isArgumentException, String argumentName)
 at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.CheckKeyMatchesEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySetForType, Boolean forAttach)
 at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry(IEntityWrapper wrappedObject, EntityKey passedKey, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName, Boolean isAdded)
 at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
 at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
 at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
 at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
 at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: Call stack may be useful.

Comment: looks like lastQuery is null so dbContext.Set<T>() failed. maybe something wrong with production connectionstring or production DB out of date?

Comment: lastQuery is not null. i can see the query and it is correct.

Comment: http://referencesource-beta.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/DataEntity/System/Data/EntityKey.cs#bba46cbee90bb12c may help

Answer (score 2):

think i figured it out.

since this view is using db first, a primary key has to be defined.

in this case, there was no primary key column, so PK was composite of few fields:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<V_MVC_USER_ACTION_PERMISSION>().HasKey(u => new { u.LOGIN_NAME, u.CONTROLLER_NAME, u.ACTION_NAME, u.APPLICATION_NAME });
```

and in production a bunch of records were coming back with null action_name

this appears to be a dbcontext no no, and it will trip with a null context exception.

as a interim solution, i added a filter to my view

> where Action_Name is not null

however, it would be nice to find a more comprehensive solution, where all such rows would be ignored instead of nulling the whole return value.